# Chrome extension doesn't work with dev-tools open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating my own Chrome Extension which is for use as a helper on a website. To do this, it reads a specific element on the website and then console.log() it.  The extension is a statically injected content-script.It works perfectly fine when dev-tools isn't open when the page fist loads, but the console.log() prints null if dev-tools is open on first load.

```
var board = document.getElementById('board-board');
var board_elements = board.getElementsByTagName('div');
....
console.log("number of elements in board class:" + board_elements.length);
```

without dev-tools open: number of elements in board class:36

with dev-tools open: number of elements in board class:0

This is weird behaviour. Is this a problem with my own computer, code, or a bug with Chrome?

Comment: If you use a docked devtools it may change the page viewport size, so its content is rendered differently. Try undocking devtools into a separate window. If this doesn't help it may be a bug in devtools or the site detects devtools explicitly and changes behavior accordingly. The workaround is to use MutationObserver or postpone processing in setTimeout.

Comment: I'm having the same problem at the moment. I made sure there wasn't a break point or something that causes it. Did you find something that helped? Thanks